# Loadkeys gives permission denied for normal user

Tags: linux, console, keyboard-layout

I am trying to perform loadkeys operation. For normal user, I am getting permission denied 
error.

the error is as follows.

```
<tim@testps>~% loadkeys mykeys
Loading /usr/tim/mykeys
Keymap 0: Permission denied
Keymap 1: Permission denied
Keymap 2: Permission denied
KDSKBENT: Operation not permitted
loadkeys: could not deallocate keymap 3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need root capabilities to use `loadkeys`. It is common to set the [setuid permission bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) on `loadkeys`. Setting this bit will cause any processes spawned by executing the `loadkeys` file to run as the owner of the file (usually root).

For added security, you should change `loadkeys`'s permissions to `750`, make a group for it, and add any users that need to use `loadkeys` to that group.

```
$ groupadd loadkeys             # you can use any group name 
$ chgrp loadkeys /bin/loadkeys
$ chmod 4750 /bin/loadkeys      # setuid, group- and user-only read and execution
$ gpasswd -a user loadkeys      # add user to the group
```

Comment: Very nice, though I would like to point out one minor glitch. This may or may not depend on OS, but at least with debian 9 doing `chgrp` on a file clears the setuid bit on the file so you should reorder the `chmod` after `chgrp` or else it wont work. Also I was just wondering if there's any security implications? E.g. could `loadkeys` be used to install a keylogger?